# Linq-To-SQL Code Generator - How to Modify the Template?

Tags: linq-to-sql

We're using Linq-To-SQL in one of our projects, and I like to modify the template the code generate uses to add some Code Analysis suppression attributes. Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Have a look here](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/23/linq-to-sql-t4-template-reloaded) (by Damien Guard), it provides a good rundown on using [T4 Templates](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/) for this purpose.

Also, looks like he's since posted the whole thing on CodePlex: [LINQ to SQL templates for T4](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Many of the Linq-To-SQL classes are implemented as partial classes. If you implement your own partial class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28VS.80%29.aspx) you could added the attributes to it. By using the partial class you avoid the risk of your attributes being removed the next time the Ling-To-SQL classes are generated.